# How to implement recyclerview ItemClickListener() in Firebase recycler adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I've followed this tutorial at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_tz8kbFUsU).
I manage to search the data but now I want to open the details page of selected data on recycler view. How do I get it done? At which part should I implement the `onClickListener` for recyclerview? I've tried to put `onClickListener`, intent put extra ... in method OnBindViewHolder and SetDetails, but both of them have problems to recognize my context.

Here is my current code:

```
    private void firebaseIngredientSearch(String searchIngredient) {

    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("ingName").startAt(searchIngredient).endAt(searchIngredient + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Ingredients> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ingredients>()
            .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, Ingredients.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, SearchActivity.IngredientsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, SearchActivity.IngredientsViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IngredientsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Ingredients model) {


                    holder.setDetails(model.getIngName(), model.getIngStatus(),model.getIngCategory(),model.getIngCategory());

                holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent goDetail = new Intent(, IngredientSearchDetailsActivity.class);
                            goDetail.putExtra("ingName", model.getIngName());
                            goDetail.putExtra("ingStatus", model.getIngStatus());
                            goDetail.putExtra("ingCategory", model.getIngCategory());
                            goDetail.putExtra("ingDescription", model.getIngDescription());

                            mActivity.startActivity(goDetail);
                        }
                    });



                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public IngredientsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_searched_ingredient, parent, false);
                    return new IngredientsViewHolder(view);
                }
            };

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    rvSearchResult.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static class IngredientsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View view;

    public IngredientsViewHolder(@androidx.annotation.NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(String ingName, String ingStatus, String ingCategory, String ingDescription) {

        TextView i_Name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView i_Status = view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        TextView i_Category = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
        TextView i_Description = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        ImageView iv_Status = view.findViewById(R.id.searchStatusIv);

        i_Name.setText(ingName);
        i_Status.setText(ingStatus);       
        i_Category.setText(ingCategory);
        i_Description.setText(ingDescription);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try using `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener`.

Comment: I've tried this but there is problem with Intent. It couldnt recognize my context

Comment: use `holder.itemView.getContext()` then

Comment: can you explain more? i dont get it. i already tried your suggested code but its not working

Comment: Update your code whatever you have done so far with intent where you faced problem so that i can check

Comment: already update the code

Comment: try with `holder.view.getContext().startActivity(goDetail)` instead of `mActivity`

Comment: Ok I add it as answer please accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `holder.view.setOnClickListener` to initiate `OnClickListener` and use `holder.view.getContext()` instead of `mActivity`

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent goDetail = new Intent(, IngredientSearchDetailsActivity.class);
        goDetail.putExtra("ingName", model.getIngName());
        goDetail.putExtra("ingStatus", model.getIngStatus());
        goDetail.putExtra("ingCategory", model.getIngCategory());
        goDetail.putExtra("ingDescription", model.getIngDescription());

        holder.view.getContext().startActivity(goDetail);
    }
});
```

Comment: This code is fine but it does not bring the data to next page. Can you help?

Comment: in onCreate of `IngredientSearchDetailsActivity`, did you try `getIntent().getStringExtra("ingName");` ?

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: okay my fault. Data loaded a bit slow. Evrything is fine actually. No changes need to be done for your code above, thank you.